# Elastic search: Aggregated query very slow

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, aggregate, slowdown

The below aggregated query used to run in 10 seconds. Suddenly it is taking more than 5 mins to complete. Do not know what changed.

Query:

```
    time curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/metric_alias/metrics/_search\?pretty\&routing\=123456 -d '{
      "size": 0,
      "query": { 
        "bool": { 
          "must": [ { 
               "term": { 
                  "tenantId": 123456 
               } 
             }, 
                { 
                "regexp": { 
                   "metric_name": {
                       "value": "[^.]*[.][^.]*" 
                   } 
                } 
             } ] 
          } 
       },
      "aggs": {
          "metric_name_tokens": {
              "terms": {
                  "field" : "metric_name",
                  "include": "[^.]*[.][^.]*",
                  "execution_hint": "map",
                  "size": 0
              }
          }
      }
  }' -o test.out
```

I even tried running the query after clearing out the field data cache using the below command

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear' -d '{ "fielddata": "true" }'
```

Couple of months back we changed these settings. Dont believe the issue we are seeing is related to this as it happens even after clearing out field data cache.

```
indices.breaker.fielddata.limit is set to 85%
indices.fielddata.cache.size is set to 75%
```

I recorded hot threads while the query is running.I copied the output here
https://gist.github.com/ChandraAddala/180e1d7df9e6f232344c1fe0109b01be

Any ideas on how to debug the issue?

Environment: Elastic search 1.7.1. Its a 3 node cluster with 125G RAM and 40 cores. ES runs with a heap size of 31G. metric_alias only touches 2 indices (one is not being updated anymore). Around 20GB of data. I dont see anything different in CPU and heap usage when running the query.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130827/discussion-on-question-by-chandra-elastic-search-aggregated-query-very-slow).

Answer (score -1):

According to [elastic.co's doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/_limiting_memory_usage.html)

> The relationship between `indices.fielddata.cache.size` and `indices.breaker.fielddata.limit` is an important one. If the circuit-breaker limit is lower than the cache size, no data will ever be evicted. In order for it to work properly, **the circuit breaker limit must be higher than the cache size**.

```
indices.breaker.fielddata.limit is set to 85%
indices.fielddata.cache.size is set to 75%
```

I think your `indices.breaker.total.limit` is not set and it is by default `70%`. Therefore even though your `indices.breaker.fielddata.limit` is set to `85%` `indices.breaker.total.limit` is limiting its capability.

> `indices.breaker.total.limit`:
>   The total circuit breaker wraps the request and fielddata circuit breakers to ensure that the combination of the two doesn’t use more than 70% of the heap by default.

Try:

1. Increasing `indices.breaker.fielddata.limit` to `>85%` value.
2. Decreasing  both `indices.breaker.fielddata.limit` and `indices.fielddata.cache.size` less than `60%` because why does a single query need more than 60% of the heap?